# Pandas select test dataframe columns using training dataframe columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a training dataframe that has been cleaned and has a subset of variables that the original test dataframe had. I'd like to create a new test dataframe that retains only the columns the training dataframe has.

For example,

```
train.columns=['A','D','E','G']

test.columns=['A','B','C','D','E','F','G']
```

How do I create new test_df that keeps only train.columns?

Comment: @ctj232 they can't upvote without a rep of at least 15.  If you upvoted their question, they'd have the requisite rep to upvote you.

Comment: Good point, thanks! @piRSquared

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming each `DataFrame` has columns with the same names, then you can simply select the columns from the test `DataFrame` using the `DataFrame.columns` property of the training `DataFrame` and the `[]` syntax.

Here is a working example:

```
$ train = pd.DataFrame([[0,1,2,3]],columns=['A','D','E','G'])
$ train
   A  D  E  G
0  0  1  2  3

$ test = pd.DataFrame([[0,1,2,3,4,5,6]],columns=['A','B','C','D','E','F','G'])
$ test
   A  B  C  D  E  F  G
0  0  1  2  3  4  5  6

$ test_df = test[train.columns]
$ test_df
   A  D  E  G
0  0  3  4  6
```

Comment: Yes, worked! Thank you! Would you know how to do the same thing if it was a numpy array and not a dataframe?

Comment: If you still have access to the `DataFrame` then it's as easy as `test_df.values`, but I'm not sure off the top of my head how to do so straight from a `ndarray`. If you really need to do the latter, then I think you can still use the `[]` indexing syntax as per the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html). However, if you're trying to select columns based on `str`-like labels, then I think you should keep working with the `DataFrame` and not a `ndarray`. Though, maybe I'm just missing the context of your question.